# How do you find out the URL of HTTP POST request in the ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Very simple question but I am unable to find an answer, I have a MVC 2 app in C#

I have a ActionResult the accept's HTTP POST's

How do I find out the URl of any posts to my ActionResult.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

To ease testability you should look to abstract your use of `HttpContext` as it's a pain to mock. Try wrapping your access to it in a separate object you can inject.

Comment: I just went to implement your code (i marked it as an answer becuase I remembered I done somehting similar last week and i thought it would work) and VS 2010 is throwing me an error saying HttpContextBase dosn't contain a definition for current!? Any Ideas

Comment: @simon where are you calling it from. Works in my code on VS2010 when called from obect injected in to controller constructor.

Comment: Sorry I just tried to stick it straight in the ActionResult just to get it to work. having checked the MSDN site I realise I will have to abstract it out like you said above.

Comment: @simon or get it in the controller and pass to the ActionResult